# Exercise 3.2 of Do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry".

Tags: differential-geometry, orthogonality

I am trying to do exercise 3.2 of Do Carmo's *Riemannian Geometry*. After constructing the natural metric in the tangent bundle of a Riemannian manifold, he defines "horizontal vector to the fiber". Its meaning is explained in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210238/horizontal-vector-in-tangent-bundle) question, but I am trying to do it again.

The set
$\pi^{-1}(p)=\{(p,v):v\in T_{p}M\}\subseteq TM$ can be considered as a submanifold of $TM$. In fact, it is a submanifold such that 
$$
T_{(p,v)}TM=T_{(p,v)}(\pi^{-1}(p))\oplus H_{(p,v)}
$$
for certain vector space $H_{(p,v)}$. We say that a vector $W\in T_{(p,v)}TM$ is horizontal to the fiber $\pi^{-1}(p)$ if $W\in H_{(p,v)}$. A differentiable curve
$\alpha(t)$ in $TM$
 is said to be horizontal to the fiber if $\alpha'(t)\in H_{\alpha(t)}$ for all $t$. I have to prove that $\alpha(t)=(p(t),v(t))$ is horizontal if and only if $v(t)$ is parallel along $p(t)$ in $M$.

I do not know how to prove it because the decomposition of $T_{(p,v)}TM$ looks too abstract for me to work with it. Any help would be appreciated.